# How is L almost universal?

Tags: set-theory

I'm reading Jech's Axiom of Choice, and when he makes his case that the constructible universe L is a model of ZFC, he says it's "easy to see" that it's transitive and almost universal.  I see transitive, but how is it almost universal?  (That is, every subset that's a set is also subset of an element.)

For reference, his definition of L is the union across all ordinals of, for non-limit ordinals, the intersection of the predecessor's power set and the same's closure under Gödel operations, and for limit ordinals, the union of all values within.

Comment: You wrote "union" when you meant "intersection" in the definition of $L_{\alpha+1}$.

Comment: D'oh - it would indeed be easy to see if it were the union, wouldn't it?  (Why did you remove the tag "model-theory"?  Surely the constructible universe is a model theory topic?)

Comment: Nope, this is not a model theory question. Even though $L$ is a model of set theory. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of almost universal is wrong!  For $L$ to be almost universal means that if $A$ is any set with $A\subseteq L$, then there is some set $B\in L$ such that $A\subseteq B$ (but $A$ itself may not be in $L$).

To prove this, just note that for each $a\in A$, there is some least ordinal $\alpha_a$ such that $a\in L_{\alpha_a}$.  If $\beta$ is the supremum of all these ordinals, then $a\in L_\beta$ for all $a\in A$.  So $A\subseteq L_\beta$, and since $L_\beta\in L$ this means we can take $B=L_\beta$.

Comment: Thanks - I see now.